# How can I write a function stub for stat() function?

Tags: c, posix, stat

I am trying to write a stub for the function stat() from <sys/stat.h>.
I was able to successfully do this for fstat with the following code:

```
static int fstat_count;
static int fstat_fail_instance;
int my_fstat(const int fd, struct stat * st) {
  fstat_count ++;
  if (fstat_count == fstat_fail_instance) {
    return EINVAL;
  }
  st->st_size = ST_SIZE;
  return EOK;
}
#undef fstat
#define fstat my_fstat
```

When I try to do this with stat, I get errors like:

```
mkqfs_file_test.c:28:20: error: storage size of ‘sb’ isn’t known
  const struct stat sb;
```

which i believe is because when I do the
`#undef stat`
`#define stat my_stat`
like i do for fstat, it is undefining the struct stat not the function.
Any idea how I can resolve this, ie only undefine/redefine function?

Comment: You can eliminate the error by undefine (delete) the function that is causing the error.

Comment: What do you mean by "stub"? Do you mean you are rewriting your own version?

Comment: The definition of `struct stat` must be visible from `const struct stat sb;`.

Comment: Please  show the code that _doesn't_ work as well as the code that does.

Comment: What is a stub?

Comment: Did you try defining `struct my_stat`?

Comment: `i believe is because when I do the #undef stat #define stat my_stat like i do for fstat` Then don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] I get errors like:
>
> ```
> mkqfs_file_test.c:28:20: error: storage size of ‘sb’ isn’t known
>   const struct stat sb;
> ```
>
> which i believe is because when I do the `#undef stat` `#define stat my_stat` like i do for fstat, it is undefining the struct stat not the
> function.

No, `#undef stat` does not undefine any function or any struct type.  It undefines any previous definition of a *preprocessor macro* with that name.  As such, it is probably unnecessary, and at worst it is harmless.  In the unlikely event that there were such an existing macro definition, however, a conforming program does need to undefine that before redefining it.

The problem is rather with the `#define`.  If the definition of the `stat` macro is visible where your struct declaration appears then it will be expanded where that identifier is used as a structure tag.  As a result, this ...

> ```
>   const struct stat sb;
> ```

... expands to ...

```
  const struct my_stat sb;
```

.  There being no definition of a type `struct my_struct` visible in scope, that declaration is not permitted.  As the compiler says, it doesn't know how much space to provide for a `struct my_stat`, nor would it be usable anyway because the compiler doesn't know what any of its members are, either.  Note that this does not prevent declaring or using pointers to a `struct my_stat`, but that has its own issues.

> Any idea how I can resolve this, ie only undefine/redefine
> function?

Again, you are not undefining any function.  There is no completely clean way to use a macro to substitute your `my_stat()` for `stat()` on account of `stat` being used for related purposes in different namespaces.  There are three main things you could do:

1. Use a function-like macro instead:

   ```
   #define stat(p,b) my_stat((p),(b))
   ```

   In that event, you must ensure that there is no attempt to compute a pointer to `stat`.  This is probably your best option.
2. Omit the `#undefine` and `#define` altogether, and name your replacement function `stat()`, the same as the original.  This relies on the linker to choose your locally-defined version over the library version, which it probably will do.  That risks having wider impact than you intend, however.
3. Before the `#undefine`, declare a `typedef` for `struct stat`:

   ```
   typedef struct stat struct_stat;
   #undefine stat
   #define stat my_stat
   ```

   Then use the `typedef` instead of type `struct stat` everywhere that your macro definition is visible:

   ```
   struct_stat sb;
   ```

Comment: If the code being instrumented never takes a pointer to `stat`, OP could define a *function-like* renaming macro and have it affect only the function, not the struct tag.

Comment: Thanks, @zwol, you're right.  Updated.

Comment: *In that event, you must ensure that no whitespace is inserted between the macro name and the parentheses at any of the call sites* -- This is not right.  Absence of whitespace is only required when a function-like macro is *defined*, not when it is used.  What OP does have to avoid, though, is *taking a pointer to* `stat`, which will bypass the rename.

Comment: Fixed, @zwol.  Thanks again.